# validate a url but do not allow urls with https:// or http://

Tags: regex

I need to find a regex that will validate a url but without http:// or https:// i.e urls should not consist of https:// or http:// as I will be appending that to urls in my code.

Example:

```
www.google.com (valid)
https://www.google.com (invalid)
http://www.google.com  (invalid)
master.sh (valid)
://master.sh (invalid)
jag.abcs.abcs (valid) // Edit
```

I want to match strings as valid url only that http:// and https:// should not be allowed.

```
Any Protocol name in the url are invalid
```

Comment: which language will execute this?

Comment: and will `file://` or `ftp://` be valid?

Comment: @Taha Paksu I am using pattern matching in html input.

Comment: @TahaPaksu file:// or ftp:// will not be valid

Comment: So basically, you don't want the protocol to be included in urls. Would you prefer using some javascript on validation?

Comment: /^([a-z]*.?[a-z]*.[a-z]*)$/.test('://master.sh');

Comment: ^(?!http|https)(www.)?[a-zA-Z0-9]+.([a-z]*)$

Comment: <input  type='text' pattern='myRegex'/> I will be using regex like this.

Comment: @BadMiscuit It does not match jag.abcs.abc  even though https://jag.abcs.abc is valid url

Comment: Better UX calls for you prepending the scheme to the URL _only_ if the user doesn't give one. Throwing an error on an invalid scheme is fine.

Comment: Also, watch out... resources returned by the `http://` scheme are not the same as those returned by the `https://` scheme - thus you cannot "_automatically prepend the scheme_" without the potential for confusion or incorrect fetches.

Comment: This might help: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL#Syntax

Comment: Could you append the protocol first, and then validate the whole URL?

Answer (score 0):

```
console.log(/^([a-z]*.?[a-z]*.[a-z]*)$/.test('www.google.com'));
console.log(/^([a-z]*.?[a-z]*.[a-z]*)$/.test('http://www.google.com'));
console.log(/^([a-z]*.?[a-z]*.[a-z]*)$/.test('master.sh'));
console.log(/^([a-z]*.?[a-z]*.[a-z]*)$/.test('://master.sh'));
```

Comment: I guess you forgot to escape the dots.

Comment: example pls @Taha

Comment: you need to write `\.` to match the dots. This way the dots match any character.

Comment: [a-z]*.?  covers your concern

Comment: Ok, try this: `console.log(/^([a-z]*.?[a-z]*.[a-z]*)$/.test('mastersh'))` returns true.

Comment: And this returns false. `console.log(/^([a-z]*\.?[a-z]*\.[a-z]*)$/.test('mastersh'))`

Answer (score 0):

> ^([a-z0-9-]+\.)*([a-z0-9]+)(\.[a-z]+){1,3}$

is what you want.

https://regex101.com/r/CNcn11/1

**Testing:**

```html
<form method="post" action="/" onsubmit="return false;">
  http://<input type="text" required pattern="^([a-z0-9-]+\.)*([a-z0-9]+)(\.[a-z]+){1,3}$">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  <br><b>Note:</b> If you don't see a validation error, it passes.
</form>
```